# Asp.net Mvc 3 connection string issue

Tags: .net, sql, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, appharbor

I just created some hosting space for my web app. However, when I change the connection string to point to my provider's SQL server I recieve an error.

The string is as follows:

```
   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=d5d3955e-1183-4e10-8892-9f9d005af0a8.sqlserver.sequelizer.com;Initial Catalog=dbd5d3955e11834e1088929f9d005af0a8;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=juydqjglrdwrhgsr;Password=***********" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="TraxzDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DBModel.csdl|res://*/Models.DBModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.DBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=d5d3955e-1183-4e10-8892-9f9d005af0a8.sqlserver.sequelizer.com;Initial Catalog=dbd5d3955e11834e1088929f9d005af0a8;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=juydqjglrdwrhgsr;Password=***********&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I receive this weird error:

```
Login failed for user 'juydqjglrdwrhgsr'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'juydqjglrdwrhgsr'.

Source Error: 


Line 32:                     <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
Line 33:                     @{
Line 34:                         if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
Line 35:                         {
Line 36:                          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin Controls", "Index", "Admin")</li> 

Source File: c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Traxz\Traxz\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml    Line: 34 

Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'juydqjglrdwrhgsr'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5064474
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2275
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +35
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) +183
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) +239
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +195
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +232
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +185
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +33
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +524
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +479
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +108
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder.Open(HttpContext context, Boolean revertImpersonate) +95
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation) +206
   System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username) +847
   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username) +58
   System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.IsInRole(String role) +182
   ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Traxz\Traxz\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:34
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +272
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +81
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +187
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer) +52
   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass7.<RenderPageCore>b__6(TextWriter writer) +203
   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +42
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.WriteTo(TextWriter writer, HelperResult content) +45
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +48
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +178
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +338
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +196
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +220
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +303
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +260
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8963149
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

I am assuming the connection string is doing something incorrectly, can anyone shed some insights into this? Need to getting this hosting up and running in order to proceed with my school project. :)

Update: I am using AppHarbor for hosting and I have been hunting this issue down and found this:

```
  If you take advantage of the Sequelizer MySQL and MS SQL Server add-ons, SQLSERVER_CONNECTION_STRING and SQLSERVER_URI settings will be injected into your application appSettings. SQLSERVER_CONNECTION_STRING_ALIAS will also be inserted if you add an alias. Further, the connection string will be placed in the connectionStrings element with name set to the alias if one is specified.

The uri is of the following format: sqlserver://username:password@hostname/databasename. If you want, you can create your own connection string (if, for example, you need a custom one for Entity Framework). Here's an example of building a standard connection string:

var uriString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLSERVER_URI"];
var uri = new Uri(uriString);
var connectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    DataSource = uri.Host,
    InitialCatalog = uri.AbsolutePath.Trim('/'),
    UserID = uri.UserInfo.Split(':').First(),
    Password = uri.UserInfo.Split(':').Last(),
}.ConnectionString;
```

I have no idea what this really means tho.. Do I need to add a new connection string? and if so how do I create one to map to my entities that I have created?

Comment: BTW I have connected to the SQL server through VS server explorer and the tables are in there and I just copied and pasted the connection string from the properties box.

Comment: Have you created the database user with the above username-password and gave it permissions for the said database ??

Comment: Can you connect **as juydqjglrdwrhgsr** to that SQL server (using the password you have in the config), and access the db? Or are you currently connecting as yourself? I'm also a bit dubious to the idea of connecting to your *provider's* sql-server (usually in private segment of their data-centre) from your VS tools (on your local machine) - are you tunnelling here?

Comment: Yes the above password and user name are correct, I use them to login to the SQl server using managment tools. It is the password and user name my host has provided me, I just straight copied and pasted it.

Comment: Also I am switching from an .mdf compact SQL- do I have to regenerate the .edmx file to map to the SQL server from my provider? Or can I use the existing one, since the two DB's have cloned data?

Comment: Are you using multiple db's - one for the app and another for authentication/authorization?

Comment: nope, both the app and authentication/authorization are contained in the same DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by modifying the applicationServices connection string:

```
<add name="TraxzDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DBModel.csdl|res://*/Models.DBModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.DBModel.msl;&#xD;&#xA;         provider=System.Data.SqlClient;&#xD;&#xA;         provider connection string=&quot;&#xD;&#xA;         Data Source=YOURPROVIDERDATASOURCE;&#xD;&#xA;         User ID=YourUserName; &#xD;&#xA;         Password=YourPassword;&#xD;&#xA;         Initial Catalog=YourCatalog;&#xD;&#xA;         Persist Security Info=True;&#xD;&#xA;      MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Then under the .tt classes for me it was "Dbcontext.context.tt" we add the following

```
   string baseConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TraxzDBEntities"].ConnectionString;

    EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
    entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
    entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = baseConnectionString;
    entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/";

    return entityBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: How did you modify the applicationservices connection string?